# Posterior probability, normalized

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, posterior

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Calculate the posterior probability that µ is less than 115.

How can I normalize this to find the probability?
Is it
$$P\left(Z < {{115 - \text {posterior mean}} \over {\text {posterior variance}}}\right)?$$
Or does the denominator have to be square rooted?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is lacking some context, but maybe it would help to think of it like this: if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, how would I standardize $X$? I'd have to subtract the mean and divide by the square root of the variance to get
$$
\frac{X-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}\sim N(0,1).
$$